# How to get values from usercontrol

Tags: wpf

It's might be a simple question, but I'm quite new in WPF and C#. 
  **Background of my question:** I have several usercontrols used as configuration menu, one of them is displayed at one time. And each usercontrol has a lot of checkboxes, textboxes and comboxes in it. Now, I want to pass the values from the usercontrols to mainwindow.
  What should I do? I'm really bothered by this issue. Please help me!!

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Start" Margin="103,12,315,273" Click="Start_Click" />
         <!--<Frame Name="myframe"/>-->
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControlInstance1" Height="200" Width="180" />
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControlInstance" Height="200" Width="180"/>
    <Button Content="ShowContent" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,15,0,0" Name="ShowContent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Click="Show_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool btn_ConfigTest = false;
    public bool btn_ConfigTest2 = false;
    public bool Flag = true;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string myvalue1 = myUserControlInstance1.Ischecked;
        //myframe.Content = new UserControl1();
        string myvalue2 = myUserControlInstance.Value;
    } 
}
```

Myusercontrol.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    DependencyModel mymodel = new DependencyModel();
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = mymodel;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string),
          typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata("abc"));


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //double Result = mymodel.Value;
        //mymodel.Value = 1234;
    }

}
```

Myusercontrol.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="parent"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="#FFD4CE61" Height="200" Width="180" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}">
    <TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,63,0,0" x:Name="mytextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Text="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox1" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,109,0,0" x:Name="mycheckBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Usercontrol1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="parent"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">


<Grid Background="#FF793D6F" Height="200" Width="180" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}">
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,33,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,85,0,0" Name="mycheckBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Ischecked}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Usercontrol1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    //DependencyModel mymodel = new DependencyModel();
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = mymodel;

    }

    public string Ischecked
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Ischecked", typeof(string),
      typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("true"));


    public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your code that you have written..

Comment: I think you should go read about WPF, data binding and MVVM, especially if you have only WinForms experience. If you then have a specific problem, you can come back here and ask.

Comment: For sure, I have updated my question with my code. Please help me, it really driving my crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: For each control in your user control, you need to make a property in code behind. In the get block you return the property which you wish to access in main window.

Step 2: Build the project. Add the user control in your main window

Step 3: When you use the user control in main window, in code behind you can set usecontrol-name(in mainwindow.xaml).propert-name(property made in code behind of user control)= value-you-wish-to-set

Comment: My solustion now is just like you said. I use <local:myusercontrol1 name="myusercontrol1"> in MainWindow.xaml, then in MainWindow.xaml.cs I can access to myusercontrol1.value1.  The problem is: I cannot dynamic select which usercontrol to show in Mainwindow. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: can you share your code? It will become lot convenient to figure out what needs to be changed

Comment: I have updated my question which has my code attached. The problem is that I cannot dynamiclly show my usercontrol. I have tried to use a frame control, then I can dynamically show it, while I cannot read the usercontrol values in Mainwindow. It's very nice of you if you can offer some advice. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think every public property in your .xaml.cs will be accessible publicly. If you want to get values from the xaml, then the safest way is to make public property to access the xaml (name the xaml control first). You don't need dependency property to do so.

Below is the example of my own project. It isn't made to match your OP, but I hope you can understand the point.

XAML

```
<UserControl ...>
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid ...>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="octaveTopRow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="noteRow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="octaveBotRow"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

XAML.CS

```
public partial class NotationBox : UserControl
{
    public double TotalBotHeight
    {
        get { return octaveBotRow.ActualHeight; }
    }

    public NotationBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. In your code ,you can get the value just in usercontrol.xaml.cs, hwo can I pass the value to mainwindow.